# Firebase Admin SDK on .net Project installed with Nuget always gives me an error

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, nuget, firebase-admin

I'm trying to install Firebase Admin on a .Net application using nuget. Everything looks good:

- The references point to the right locations
- The packages folder is populated with the binaries
- The config files contain the right references and have the right versions
- The dependencies are all included
- The project builds

But, every time I try to use a method that includes the FirebaseAdmin class, it throws a System.IO.FileNotFoundException. I have tried numerous solutions:

- Reinstalling all the packages
- Cleaning the solution and then reinstalling
- Deleting the package folder and restoring packages
- Installing in a clean environment and manually referencing the DLLs

Nothing. Is anyone else having this error? If so, how did you resolve it?

P.S. I'm somewhat green on Nuget. I've been working on a project that uses it for a few years. My understanding is that it's supposed to be a streamlined and simple package manager. I haven't had to install a new package until now. My experience has been anything but - knowing the ins and outs of a supposedly good package manager was at the bottom of my priority list until now. Any help, even relatively obvious pointers, is welcome.

EDIT 1: I am aware that Firebase requires initialization, but I've been trying to put initialization inside the model's method rather than the project startup.

```
namespace Sis.OneSis.Business.Models.Notification
{
    [DataContract]
    public class NotificationFramework
    {

    #region Methods
    public static void SendNotification(int userId, int siteId, int yearId, string enumeration, int object_ID, string payload)
    {

        try
        {
            // Running the stored procedure
            V10Data.V10DataContextProvider modelContainer = new V10Data.V10DataContextProvider();
            List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Enumeration", Value = enumeration, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
            parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Payload", Value = payload, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Xml, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
            parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Object_ID", Value = object_ID, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
            parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@User_ID", Value = userId, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
            parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Site_ID", Value = siteId, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
            parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Year_ID", Value = yearId, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
            DataSet dataSet = modelContainer.ExecuteGetProcedure("spNTF_ProcessNotification", parameterList);

            // Retrieving the notifications
            List<NotificationLogDTO> notificationLogs = new List<NotificationLogDTO>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                NotificationLogDTO notificationLog = new NotificationLogDTO();
                notificationLog.ID = row.Field<int>("ID");
                notificationLog.NotificationType_ID = row.Field<int>("NotificationType_ID");
                notificationLog.NotificationEvent_ID = row.Field<int>("NotificationEvent_ID");
                notificationLog.User_ID = row.Field<int>("User_ID");
                notificationLog.Object_ID = row.Field<int>("Object_ID");
                notificationLog.Student_ID = row.Field<int?>("Student_ID");
                notificationLog.Message = row.Field<string>("Message");
                notificationLog.Subject = row.Field<string>("Subject");
                notificationLog.AddedOn = row.Field<DateTime>("AddedOn");
                notificationLog.AddedBy = row.Field<int>("AddedBy"); 
                notificationLog.EmailAddress = row.Field<string>("EmailAddress");
                notificationLogs.Add(notificationLog);
            }

            // Sending the notifications
            using (CrudEngine crudEngine = new CrudEngine())
            {
                string defaultEmailAddress = "noreply@tylertech.com";
                var version = Sis.OneSis.Server.Configuration.AppConfiguration.RetrieveResourceVersion();
                if (version != null)
                {
                    if (version.Value == "V9")
                    {
                        defaultEmailAddress = crudEngine.Read<V9DomainModel.tblDistrict>()
                            .Where(o => o.blnExternal == false)
                            .Select(o => o.strEmailDefaultEAddress)
                            .SingleOrDefault();
                    } else
                    {
                        defaultEmailAddress = crudEngine.Read<V10DomainModel.SystemSetting>()
                            .Select(o => o.NotificationEmail)
                            .SingleOrDefault();
                    }
                }
                Dictionary<int, List<NotificationLogDTO>> userMobileNotifications = new Dictionary<int, List<NotificationLogDTO>>();
                foreach (NotificationLogDTO notification in notificationLogs)
                {
                    switch (notification.NotificationType_ID)
                    {
                        // Email
                        case 1:
                            SendEmailParameters parameters = new SendEmailParameters();
                            parameters.EmailFrom = defaultEmailAddress;
                            parameters.EmailTo = notification.EmailAddress;
                            parameters.Body = notification.Message;
                            parameters.Subject = notification.Subject;
                            sendEmailDTO.SendEmail(parameters, -1, -1, -1, userId, "Classroom");
                            break;

                        // Mobile Notification
                        case 3:
                            if (!userMobileNotifications.Keys.Contains(notification.User_ID))
                            {
                                userMobileNotifications.Add(notification.User_ID, new List<NotificationLogDTO>());
                            }
                            userMobileNotifications[notification.User_ID].Add(notification);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                // Sending mobile notifications
                FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
                if (firebaseApp == null)
                {
                    DataTable credentials = modelContainer.ExecuteSqlQuery("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM NTF_FirebaseCredentials");
                    if (credentials.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string firebaseJSON = credentials.Rows[0].Field<string>("FirebaseJSON");
                        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
                        {
                            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(firebaseJSON),
                        });
                    }
                }
                FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance;
                if (firebaseMessaging == null)
                {
                    firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.GetMessaging(firebaseApp);
                }
                List<NotificationUserDevice> userDevices = NotificationUserDevice.GetUserDevices(userId, userMobileNotifications.Keys.ToList());
                List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
                foreach (NotificationUserDevice userDevice in userDevices)
                {
                    List<NotificationLogDTO> notifications = userMobileNotifications[userDevice.User_ID];
                    foreach (NotificationLogDTO notification in notifications)
                    {
                        Message message = new Message();
                        message.Token = userDevice.DeviceToken;
                        FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification mobileNotification = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification();
                        mobileNotification.Title = notification.Subject;
                        mobileNotification.Body = notification.Message;
                        message.Notification = mobileNotification;
                    }
                }
                firebaseMessaging.SendAllAsync(messages);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errMsg = "An error occurred -";
            LogServices.Error(ex, "userId:{0}:customMessage:{1}:", userId, errMsg);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue to my problem. One of our solutions was built into a separate project that was referenced by IIS. That project needed manual references to the DLLs, so I updated that project's references manually and it worked from there. If you are working on a tiered project with multiple solutions, this could apply to you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of NuGet is accurate for the vast majority of packages however FirebaseAdmin requires some additional set-up.

The whole process is described in detail here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk

I will point out the most important things here (like a TL;DR). Firstly you will need a firebase private key in the form of a json file (steps described succinctly in the link under "Initialize the SDK"). After that, make sure you run this bit of code before any calls to firebase related functions.

```
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
{
    Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("path/to/what/you/downlowded.json"),
});
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Oh, hold up - does it require me to initialize this somewhere in my .Net project before I use it in a model? I'll post a code snippet if it's relevant.

Comment: Yes. Make sure you initialize this before any calls to firebase related methods (only once).